# Sourcegear Vault: How do I get an automated list of checked out files?

Tags: sourcegear-vault

**Question:**

How can I get a list of all checked out files per user in Sourcegear Vault?

**Use of this functionality:**

From time to time we have developers leaving files checked out and although this results in drastic punishment (they owe a coffee to the person who needed the checked out file) we are still left with files checked out and work held up.

We would like to display a list of all current number of files checked out by each developer. This way they can check if they have anything checked out before they go home or out the office.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Vault Client app, use the Search tab at the bottom of the window.

Select **Search By:** *"Checked Out By"* to see a list of all files checked out by a specific user, or by any user.

You can choose to search a specific sub-folder, or from the root, recursively or not.

To automate this, use the Vault Command-Line client (vault.exe)

```
vault -host myhost.mydomain -user something -password something -repository myrepo listcheckouts
```

Will give you a list, in XML, of all checked-out files and their users.  You can transform the results, or use the command-line client's source code (provided as an example with the Vault .NET API) as a starting point to write your own version.

The various clients and APIs can be grabbed from http://sourcegear.com/vault/downloads.html - didn't want to link to a specific version that would be outdated after the next release.

Comment: This would work if I wanted to do it manually, but I want this information to be displayed in a report like format.

Comment: Gotcha. Edited my answer to add some automation suggestions.